# Detect if a single group is open/close and close/open it

Tags: vba

I know how to close all the groups at once using outline in the VBA like this:

```
'''' Close outline groups.
With sh.Outline
    .ShowLevels _
        RowLevels:=1, _
        ColumnLevels:=1
End With
```

I also know how to open all the groups at once using outline in the VBA like this:

```
'''' Open outline groups.
With sh.Outline
    .ShowLevels _
        RowLevels:=2, _
        ColumnLevels:=2
End With
```

But, how on earth can I open/close a single group!? And how do I detect if it is opened/closed!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two code snippets as starting point:

```vb
Public Function isCollapsed(c As Range) As Boolean
isCollapsed = c.EntireRow.ShowDetail
End Function


Public Sub collapse(c As Range)
With c.EntireRow
    If .ShowDetail = False Then
        .ShowDetail = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

You pass the cell which you want to check to the sub/function